# Работа с GSON(android)

Tags: android, json, retrofit, gson

Как можно конвертировать GSON в JSON?

При отправке запроса на сервер(сервер wp) я получаю ответ подобное

```
[
{
    "id": 504,
    "date": "2016-10-07T11:52:53",
    "date_gmt": "2016-10-07T08:52:53",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "http://andrq.com/?p=504"
    },
    "modified": "2016-10-07T11:52:53"
```

В response  пытаюсь конвертировать ответ в JSON

```
Call<Object> call = api.getPost();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
            String s = response.body().toString();
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonArray.getString(1) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

И собственно сам GSON builder

```
private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .baseUrl("andrq.com")
        .build();
```

Когда я вызываю Toast то ничего не выводится хотя в объект заносится JSON
и еще вылетает исключение

> W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
>   W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:393)
>   W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
>   W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.readArray(JSONTokener.java:429)
>   W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:103)

Comment: Или это может происходить из-за асинхронной работы?

Comment: Retrofit сам разберется в парсингом json, вам только нужно при запросе указать какой объект вы получаете. Вместо `Call<Object>` должно быть `Call<MyObject>`, где MyObject - это класс, соответствующий вашему json. Так как json вы тут привели частично, то как этот класс будет выглядеть никто не знает. Побдобнее про gson [тут](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md)

Comment: То есть если я укажу в своем MyObject поле с JsonObject то я смогу туда поместить ответ?

Comment: Нет, с JsonObject вообще не нужно работать.
Если у вас, например, такой json: `{"id": 504}`, то у вашего класса будет одно поле `int id`. В вашем случае полей больше и скорее всего корневой объект - это массив или список, но суть та же. Gson позволяет парсить json в ваши объекты, для этого он и нужен.

Comment: можете подсказать, если обыкновенные поля int id, String date...и тд понятно как описать, что делать с guid:{render:http://....} ? Представить в виде ArrayList? Мол ArrayList<String> guid ?

Comment: В MyObject поле `Guid guid`
А в классе Guid будет поле `String rendered`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49223/discussion-between-heaven-and-lllyct).